Free Speech - is it a Torah principle?
Does the Torah have a principle of free speech? What is it?
Note, I am not talking about all speech, such as Lashon Hara etc.  I am talking about how the term is mainly used in modern discourse; i.e. should we allow evil people to speak their evil ideas, like Neo Nazis etc.?

On the one hand, there's the argument for: let them speak, rather than forcing them underground, where their ideas will fester, unchallenged. Out in the open, they can be challenged, rebutted and their evil exposed.

On the other hand, there's the argument against: brainwashing is real, and easy; giving Hitler y'msh a microphone is what caused so much of Germany to turn Nazi. Evil people with evil ideas should not be given microphones.


So, can we draw any wisdom or rules from the Torah on how to manage this tension?

Rabbi Jonathan Sacks once said: "Free speech is not speech that costs nothing. It is speech that respects the freedom and dignity of others. Forget this and free speech becomes very expensive indeed."

The Torah doesn't even believe in free thought.

@shmosel free thought doesn’t influence others.

Is free anything a Torah principle? We are all slaves to God. We have no freedoms. Eg. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/144423/759

@DoubleAA given the specifics of the question "...how the term is mainly used in modern discourse; i.e. should we allow evil people to speak their evil ideas, like Neo Nazis etc.?", it might be better to bring cases of what the Beit Din does to those who say things that are not allowed to say, such as speaking derogatorially about Sages, informing to the authorities, blasphemy laws etc

Judaism does not have a clear statement on freedom of speech.  So must examine the issues one by one.
On the one hand, the Talmud itself testifies to such freedom, within broad bounds.  It includes vigorous and feisty discussions, followed by minority opinions, followed by the majority opinion, which is usually the final decision.  Opposing viewpoints are welcome.  As we often hear, two Jews will produce three opinions.  The Mishnah says:

אֵיזֶהוּ חָכָם, הַלּוֹמֵד מִכָּל אָדָם -- Who is wise? He who learns from everyone. [Avot 4:1]

However, Jewish law prohibits many types of speech for ethical and religious reasons: blaspheming God, pretending to be a prophet, speaking against the king, disrespecting a rabbi or contradicting him in private or in public [Rashi on Numbers 25:6-7], speaking ahead of someone who is wiser [Avot 5:7], cursing people, or teaching the opposite of a ruling of the Sanhedrin.  The most reviled form of speech is malicious gossip, or lashon hara.
Also prohibited is being rude or insulting (Onaat devarim אוֹנָאַת דְבָרִים, literally “hurting people with words”.  The Talmud says:

When the Torah states “Do not wrong one another” וְלֹ֤א תוֹנוּ֙ אִ֣ישׁ אֶת־עֲמִית֔וֹ – [Leviticus 25:17], it includes intentionally saying something that will hurt, frighten or embarrass someone. Whoever does this has no share in the World to Come. [Bava Metzia 58b-59a; Sefer HaChinuch 338; Shulḥan Arukh, Choshen Mishpat 228:1.]

Also, lies are forbidden, unless uttered to save a life, keep the peace, make people feel good, appear humble and modest, or protect oneself from loss or harm.

+1 If an evil person with an evil ideology is able to speak it without breaking any of the specific speech laws you mentioned, does the Torah say we must let him speak, we must stop him, or something else?

As far as I know, there is nothing against letting him do it.

I think there are two angles on this.
Unfair comparison
Free speech seems to be a democratic principle, and is a necessity in a system where "right and wrong" are not absolute (or at least, impossible to full capture, systematically), so should be something that the people can discuss and debate. Hence, the law of free speech is enshrined in constitutions etc. you can't be suppressed by force simply for saying what you believe is right or wrong.
Torah, on the other hand, is a system of right and wrong, therefore it does not allow someone to stand up and advocate for idolatry, for example. However, it does have somewhat of an equivalent - debating the Oral Law. The Oral Law has become fuzzy over time, so we have had to engage in honest debate to try to get to the bottom of the Law, but ultimately a decision should be made and adhered to, once the debate has arrived at its conclusions, and at that point we are no longer free to debate it (although we can always re-open a debate with a strong enough kashe)
Free will
The Torah explains that we are meant to have free will, and not be coerced to be good. Therefore we are given, practically, freedom of speech, and other freedoms, to a great degree. The difference is, that freedom is only for the purpose of using it for good. If it is not used for good, then, unlike democratic free speech, it can be punished. If someone wants to advocate for idolatry, they can, but they will be executed!

Sources for pretty much everything I've written here can be found in this answer: Why do Rabbis say that HaShem was mistaken and HaShem states that He was defeated and that He must obey the Rabbis?

Aside from the laws of Lashon haRa and cases in Mishna Chagiga 2:1, the mishna Pirkei Avos 5:17 teaches:

כָּל מַחֲלֹקֶת שֶׁהִיא לְשֵׁם שָׁמַיִם, סוֹפָהּ לְהִתְקַיֵּם. וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ לְשֵׁם שָׁמַיִם, אֵין סוֹפָהּ לְהִתְקַיֵּם. אֵיזוֹ הִיא מַחֲלֹקֶת שֶׁהִיא לְשֵׁם שָׁמַיִם, זוֹ מַחֲלֹקֶת הִלֵּל וְשַׁמַּאי. וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ לְשֵׁם שָׁמַיִם, זוֹ מַחֲלֹקֶת קֹרַח וְכָל עֲדָתוֹ:
Every dispute that is for the sake of Heaven, will in the end endure; But one that is not for the sake of Heaven, will not endure. Which is the controversy that is for the sake of Heaven? Such was the controversy of Hillel and Shammai. And which is the controversy that is not for the sake of Heaven? Such was the controversy of Korah and all his congregation.

In other words, it is not the subject of discussion, but intent of the discussion that is at the core of permissibility. For example, Korach questioned validity of Aharon's appointment to kehuna by asking about a garment with 4 corners made out of techeles. Such a question is clearly forbidden due to its intent.  However, Korach could ask about the meil of Kohen Gadol, which had 4 corners and was made out of techeles, whether it was liable for tzitzis, whithout any other implications regarding anyone. That is a good question with an answer on Mi Yodeya!

@יהושעק that's exctly what I wrote.
